# Solving the second order differential equation $d^2u /dt^2 =a$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2}=a$ which $ a$ is constant, then $u=\frac{a}{2}t^2+bt+c$ on interval $ [0,T)$.

Let's say we have $a, c$. Then how can we find $b$?

Comment: It is a parameter, you have to put some constrain to get it. It is arbitrary which $b$ to take.

Comment: $$b=\left.\frac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm dt}\right|_{t=0}$$

Comment: If we assume $c$ is initial for instance.

Comment: The title should describe the problem being solved; see this and other advice in [How to ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959)

Answer (score 2):

If $u$ is your position, then $b$ is your initial speed and $c$ is your initial position. That's why you need 2 initial conditions in mechanics.